# Detect if div is clicked including childs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if a div and its child is clicked

```
$('div').click(function(e){
     if(e.target.id  == 'test')
       alert(e.target.id);
});
```

The div I need to test is #test in my html code, this code is working but if I click on child element it does nothing

How can I have target + children in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this`(element with which event was attached) instead of `event.target`(element with invoked the event) and you should use ID Selector to attach event handler i.e. `$('#test')`

```js
$('div').click(function(e) {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  text
  <button>1</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you click on the child, due to bubbling

```
 $('#test').click(function(e){
      console.log(e.target);
      //check if the target is the child you were expecting to be clicked
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if the child+parent is clicked then put click event on child element rather than parent. You can access the child elements as `div .divclass` or for immediate child `div>.divclass`.